# Read Control Value from backgroundworker thread in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm trying to read the values of the controls from a backgroundworker.

There are plenty of examples of how to update a control from a background thread, but i've not been able to find one example of how to read from it.

At the moment I have created a struct to pass to the backgroundworker, but it does not seem very elegant.

Struct:

```
public struct Arguments
    {
        public string version;
        public bool isChecked;

        public Arguments(string Version, bool IsChecked)
        {
            version = Version;
            isChecked = IsChecked;
        }

    }
```

Button Click Event

```
 Arguments pass = new Arguments(Version.Text.Trim(), (bool)Credentials.IsChecked);

 export.RunWorkerAsync(pass);
```

DoWork Event

```
ExportSolution export = new ExportSolution(this, messageBox);

Arguments pass = (Arguments)e.Argument;

export.Export(pass.version, pass.isChecked);
```

This works fine, but I would like to do the following or something similar

DoWork event

```
 ExportSolution export = new ExportSolution(this, messageBox);             

 export.Export(Access Version.Text.Trim() from here, ditto (bool)Credentials.IsChecked);
```

TIA

Comment: Do you need to access them from the background thread to get the latest and current information?  Or are you just trying to save time by not having to create a class or a struct for your DoWork argument?

Comment: I think it would be more elegant to not have a class or a struct just for the arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I've ended up doing:

```
    string version;
    bool isChecked;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = validator;

        //export.DoWork +=new DoWorkEventHandler(export_DoWork);

        export.DoWork += (sender, args) =>
        {
            ExportSolution exports = new ExportSolution(this, messageBox);

            Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => version = Version.Text.Trim()));
            Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => isChecked = (bool)Credentials.IsChecked));

            exports.Export(version, isChecked);
        };
    }
```

Where Version is a textbox and Credentials is a Checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on Code Behind, you can do the DoWork event as a Lambda expression,

eg.

```
DoWork+=(_,_)=>{...}
```

then inside the labda expression you can see the outside scope, and you can see the windows control's names, and the buttob.